# Scrolling towards left in Windows phone App page

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Can we scroll horizontally in a windows phone 8 appication just like we do vertical scrolling ?

Can anyone guide me on this part ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by horizontal scrolling? Is this like a Pivot/Panorama page, or a textbox whose text can extend past the boundaries of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to scroll content horizontally, you should take a look at the [ScrollViewer control](http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/windows-phone-7-scrollviewer-control/):

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <!-- place your content controls here -->
</ScrollViewer>
```

However, you have to take care that the content controls are properly aligned!

If suitable, you should take a look at the [Panorama](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941104%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or the [Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941098%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) control. Both support horizontal scrolling and match the Windows Phone UX.

Comment: I want to add tiles in a normal page but i want them to be availaible horizontally. So, that user can scroll left and access the tiles.

Comment: The Problem is that i want to use around 10 rectangle tiles horizontally in a proportiate order in a windows 8 style. In panorma when i place a single item and place 10 tiles in it, switching becomes difficult because scrolling is very quick in a panorma application.

Comment: Can you Suggest any changes by which i can make switching in a panorma a little slower or use a normal page with horizontal scrolling ??

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "slow scrolling"? Do you currently use one PanoramaItem for each tile?